# Line break when importing csv to mysql and sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, csv, newline

I am importing CSV data to MySQL (using 000webhost) and SQLite. I have data with line breaks in my database as such:

> My first line.\nMy second line.

it should print out like this:

> My first line. My second line.

I am developing for an Android app to display the results. I get from the database into a TextView and the data that is displayed is shown with \n as such:

> My first line.\nMy second line.

Shouldn't it escape \n and print it as a line break instead??

Comment: `\n` is not a line break; it is a backslash and a letter. Why do you think it wold be a line break?

Comment: Could the value in your csv file be stored as \\n?

Comment: @CL. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html please read "\n  : Insert a newline in the text at this point.". If that is not how you insert a new line then how do you do it?

Comment: @kanghj I tried but it prints out as text "\n" not new line

Comment: A *Java* escape sequence has nothing to do with SQL, or CSV.

Comment: @CL. I am using SQL and CSV as I said I am importing my CSV file into MySQL server and SQLite database and then reading the file using my Android app. You can also use \n I have tried a string that has \n and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a line break, use a line break:

```
IDCol,TextCol
1,hello
2,"My first line.
My second line."
```

(The CSV format is not very well specified; not all programs might be able to import this correctly.)

Comment: I am using Excel and then export the file to CSV..so you mean in Excel just use a normal alt+enter line break?

Comment: I have tried normal line break and it worked thanks a lot!